# s.m.a.r.t. data no longer available in Ubuntu 16.04 "disks" application

Tags: hard-drive

I am trying to find out the spindle speed of a /dev/sdb
It is a WD Green WD30EZRX SATA / 64MB Cache ... for some reason, maybe variable speed, the spindle speed is not listed on the sticker.

There formerly was located a place in the "disks" application to list how many times the drive had been powered on, and several other pieces of information.

I un-mounted the drive, and the gears icon still did not give the option to load the s.m.a.r.t. data.

I installed the sg3-utils or sginfo (I don't know why it is not responding to a "program ?" query, to find out all the commands that can be asked of it, because it no longer acts like it is installed

sudo sginfo -g /dev/sdb

> > > Unable to read Rigid Disk Geometry mode page (0x4) [mode_sense_10]

Comment: The Green drives are 5400 rpm.  They also live short lives before failing.  Avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `disks` app and you will notice a hamburger menu on the top right:

[image: Disks hard disk.png]

Left click the "hamburger" and the select `SMART Data & Self-Tests` from the drop down menu:

[image: Disks detail]

You don't have to install anything special this works out of the box with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Ok, I now see the hamburger menu, which shows "SMART Data & Self-Tests" and "Drive Settings" for my /dev/sda1 SSD primary boot drive.  However, when I click on /dev/sdb/ spindle drive in question, it is greyed out, un-choosable.  I even tried un-mounting the drive, but no love.

Comment: @user627430 Lots of people miss the hamburger menu. For me the SSD is greyed out. Makes me wonder what's on your SSD SMART menu?

Comment: It list a long list of the SMART attribute IDs for my SSD.  I could list all the different number types, but I don't know if that would help reach the answer about this spindle drive.  I think I just now realized why the spindle drive won't show the attributes; it is inside an external case, so the SATA cable can not talk directly to it; only through the USB to the external controller.  I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.  I need to pull it out of the case, and wire it up by sata to a desktop style board.