# USB hard drive fails to mount on boot

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, fstab, external-hdd

I have 3 identical make/model external hard drives connected by USB, and `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
[...]
UUID=1b83f30d-cb05-460f-ba98-50912a639330   /mnt/disk1  ext4    auto,defaults,nofail    0   2
UUID=b2653db0-5233-4812-a5af-bf3a8944db80   /mnt/disk2  ext4    auto,defaults,nofail    0   2
UUID=c02d2990-61b6-432d-9b20-b95643607065   /mnt/disk3  ext4    auto,defaults,nofail    0   2
[...]
```

After reboot, `df -h` looks like this:

```
[...]
/dev/sdb1       3.6T  3.1T  313G  92% /mnt/disk1
/dev/sdd1       3.6T  3.0T  484G  87% /mnt/disk3
[...]
```

As you can see, disk 2 fails to mount after every single boot or reboot. Trying to mount it manually with `sudo mount /mnt/disk2` results in `mount: /mnt/disk2: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or mount point busy.` BUT! If I then wait, 2-3  minutes after boot time, I can mount it just fine with the exact same command. So, the drive will mount *eventually*. What I'm trying to find out is

1. Why is the disk unable to mount for the first several minutes after boot and
2. How can I reliably ensure the disk mounts automatically? I don't even care if the machine takes 2-3 longer to boot, as long as the disk is mounted eventually.

Comment: I see no OS & release details provided; the software stack you're using is what I'd start with, and you didn't provide that.  You've also told it to ignore failures (nofail; or from the man page for my release - "*do not report errors for this device if it does not exist*" ie. taken from `man fstab`)

Comment: Is it also slow booting? The nofail option is best combined with the x-systemd.device-timeout option. Like `defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=4` I would run fsck on partition and also check what smartmontools say (in gnome Disks) say about drive.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application