# Error loading ubuntu boot, ubuntu live sees main boot SSD, but not storage HDD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hard-drive, data-recovery, automount

My computer is dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I have two windows drives (1TB SSD OS, and 1TB HDD storage) and two Ubuntu drives (256GB OS, and 2TB storage). I was unable to load the Ubuntu OS after having been in windows, and it would only send me to emergency mode.

Not understanding emergency mode, or which of the thousands of lines would help me diagnose the issue, I am now most interested in data recovery. I have a ubuntulive USB that has enabled me to log in to a live ubuntu session.

I can see my Ubuntu OS and recover the files from it, and I can also see my windows OS drive and windows storage drive, but I'm unable to see my Ubuntu storage drive [(picture attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP59e.png). Note, in this image, there is also a 20GB partition which I think is part of ubuntu?

If I go to disks I can see my 2TB drive there, however it is now saying there are 17MB of a Microsoft Reserved partition, and 2.0TB of unallocated space [(picture attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRrOb.png).

I've got no idea what's happened here, but I really need to get that data back! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think my Ubuntu storage used to be automounted when I would log in to Ubuntu, so does that explain why I can't see the storage drive?

Edit to respond to Oldfred's questions.

[image: Here] is the output from `lsblk -f`, apologies I don't understand what any of it really is. I think going from what I can see in disks, `sdd` is the drive in question, `sdb` is the liveusb, and `sdc` is the regular ubuntu boot ssd.

As far as was it shutdown correctly, I think so, it's also a relatively new drive so hopefully shouldn't be damaged, my PC hasn't been moved or opened etc. since it last worked.

I have installed smart and performed short and conveyance tests on the sdd drive and they are showing completed without error. Following your second link, it says that the overall assessment is "Disk is ok" but I don't really understand it, so I have again posted a screenshot below.

[image]

I have also run `sudo e2fsck -v -n /dev/sdd` on the drive. I had the following output:

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Ubuntu_data was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
```

before receiving a lot of

```
Group 14903 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
```

outputs for all the numbers up to 14903.  Then finally I received

```
Ubuntu_data: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


          11 inodes used (0.00%, out of 122101760)
        4779 non-contiguous files (43445.5%)
         956 non-contiguous directories (8690.9%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 6600380/703
     7947223 blocks used (1.63%, out of 488378646)
           0 bad blocks
          70 large files

     4027893 regular files
     2573189 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
           0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
     6601082 files
```

so it looks like my data is still there? I was a little concerned about it trying to fix things (running with `-p` or `-y`) as I'm not really sure what it does. Is this safe?

Comment: Post this and explain what partitions are what. You only need to post the part that is for your Linux data drive. `lsblk -f`. Is drive damaged? Does Smart Status show good or bad? Or was it not correctly shutdown and needs fsck (if ext4). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools
In Disks is Smart Data:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Hi @oldfred, long edit but I've done the things you've suggested. Short story, I think my data is still on there, see my output from ```e2fsck```, but I'm a little unsure about running this, is it safe to do so? I don't know what ```-p``` or ```-y``` does when it attempts to fix things. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not understand parameters of any command, you should check the man page. `man e2fsck` or `man fsck` The -y answers yes for the second set of command as it often is a long list so many yes required. And -p is auto repair, otherwise it just tells you that you have issues, but does nothing.

Comment: You misunderstand me, I understand that ```-y``` will answer yes to everything for me, or that ```-p``` will try to fix things that don't require a response, but I don't understand what it is going to do as part of its repair. What is a repair, what does it do, and can trying to do the repairs make things worse?

Comment: You have corruption. Occasionally it may not repair or make things worse. That is why we have backups. Most times it is minor & it can repair file system using internal data for files. Issue can be caused by failing drive, or abnormal shutdown, when system is in middle of writing data. Some of that then could be lost, if that was issue. Or some application that was writing data did not fully complete. You have to run command to know if it can fix issue. Otherwise you rely on backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm coming back to this after a while, as I don't know why I never did post the fix at the time.

Following on with the conversation between myself and @oldfred in the comments to my question, running `man e2fsck -y /dev/sdd` fixes whatever issue it is having. I'm then able to access the drive through terminal or file explorer.

This is really strange though. This is just a storage drive, the OS is installed on `dev/sdc`, in which all the files are instantly accessible from when I log in with a ubuntulive OS. My storage drive was set to auto-mount when the OS boots, could this be causing the issue?

To round up, the above lines have enabled me to access the drive through a ubuntulive USB OS, but I'm still unable to boot back into my original OS. I was able to recover my data, but I was unable to fix my OS installation.

If anyone knows of a way to fix it fully, I'm all ears.