# Recover Data from unmounted nvme

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, hard-drive

To give a context:
Since ~10 months I used to start my Ubuntu by going inside grub and write as follow:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt3)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.1-051901-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p3
initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.19.1-051901-generic
boot
```

Without this system just freeze with blinking `_` at the corner during start. Real problem occurs when I propably change owner of the sudo.cnf file (don't remember file name). I had to make that command in container but propably didn't. The effect is obvious I can't use any sudo command. Making in together when my dell g3 accidentaly restart my grub solution stopped working. I make live usb and tried to install fresh ubuntu next to current one to get access to old files, but process of `Removing conflicting operating system files` last forever (21h+). In the logs after this 21 hours i can see only some crud actions and a lot of`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/999) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)`. I gave up with this idea and tried get old files through `Try Linux` option. So my `lsblk` output is

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     3G  1 loop /rofs
loop1         7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2         7:2    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop3         7:3    0 237.2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2987
loop4         7:4    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop5         7:5    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop6         7:6    0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop7         7:7    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8         7:8    0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop9         7:9    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop10        7:10   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
sda           8:0    1  57.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1   4.7G  0 part /cdrom
├─sda2        8:2    1   4.9M  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    1   300K  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    1  52.6G  0 part /var/crash
                                      /var/log
nvme0n1     259:0    0     0B  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   750M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     5G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 471.2G  0 part
```

so i tried to mount `nvme0n1` - `mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt` and output is `mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3.` I tried use `sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3` to identify filesystem type but i had no output. Next `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3` output is

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p3

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

and of course given alternate superblock wont work either. I have problem with install any `smartmontools` or `tesdisk` coz of `E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`. I tried `sudo badblocks -v /dev/nvme0n1p3` and get `Pass completed, 494095360 bad blocks found. (494095360/0/0 errors)`. Then I tried to make disk image through `sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 of=my_data bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync` which succeed with 3,5 Gb file. After run testdisk at another pc I get `Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55` and then i realize that i should do `sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=my_data bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync` (whole disk not only p3) but for this i get output

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00926212 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

I also thought that maybe I choose bad option from testdisk (Intel (this one I choose), EFI GPT), so i tried to use

```
hexdump -C -n 100000 my_data
```

but i get only zeros (which might be result that i make disk image from only nvme0n1p3). At the end I can share also result from `sudo dmesg | grep nvme0n1` which is whole in

```
[ 2694.176430] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 3121868, async page read
[ 2694.176434] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 3121868, async page read
[ 2694.176439] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 3121869, async page read
...
[ 4080.276514] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 123095574, async page read
```

Do you see any chance to access old files? Maybe it will be easier to access those files from grub from old instance, than trying to mount it from live-usb? Maybe it is possible to solve problems with owner of sudo.conf and reinstall will not be nessecery?
There is output from `lsblk -e 7 -f`

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda  iso966 Jolie Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64
│                       2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                              
├─sda1
│    iso966 Jolie Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64
│                       2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                     0   100% /cdrom
├─sda2
│    vfat   FAT12 ESP   F7DB-4D56                                           
├─sda3
│                                                                           
└─sda4
     ext4   1.0   writable
                        1c62f603-24f6-43ad-87c7-e7dcb7952498   48.8G     0% /var/crash
                                                                            /var/log
nvme0n1
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p2
│                                                                           
└─nvme0n1p3
```

For **smartmontools** i have this output

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD: Input/output error
```

Cannot also click `SMART data and self-tests` coz its grey [printscreen from disks app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erxaz.png)

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 0 sectors, 0 bytes
Model: IM2P33F3A NVMe ADATA 512GB              
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 92747669-254D-443B-AD8F-8D69F42029D7
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 18446744073709551582
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Comment: This shows more info without loops which are just your snaps. `lsblk -e 7 -f` User 999 is the live installer's user and default user for install is 1000. Does smartctl show drive is ok? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools
In Disks is Smart Data:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application  SSDs do trim regularly which erases unused blocks. If drive erased trim with totally erase everything. Then backup is only recourse.

Comment: I update my post with your tips, but i am starting thinking I need to format this ssdhit and try to recover .kdbx file...

Comment: If smart tools cannot see drive that is not good. You still show partitions. Does this show anything more? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`

Comment: I added output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` . I just realize i cannot even  erase data and make fresh install coz linux dont see data to erase...

Comment: Was drive gpt before? Or were you using the old MBR with newer UEFI? Gpt has advantage of backup partition table at end of drive, but gdisk dis not finding that, just the gpt protective MBR. I would guess drive is toast. No software can work with a drive that cannot be seen.

Comment: I think it was gpt, but i base my guess on the way how I launched pc since longtime set root=(hd0, gpt3) in grub

Comment: I wonder if that could work sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
This will open the gdisk interactive mode for your NVMe disk. Once in gdisk, you can use the following steps:

Press r to enter the recovery and transformation menu.
Press g to convert GPT to MBR and leave the GPT entries in place.
Press c to set the first usable sector. Enter 34 when prompted.
Press p to view the modified partition table and verify the changes.
Press w to write the changes to the disk.
Confirm the action by typing Y.